# Handling f64 or Complex64 return types. Generics? Either?

Tags: rust, generic-programming, either

I have a functioning Rust program using real doubles (`f64`) as the underlying type and wish to extend the system such that it can also handle complex values (`num::complex::Complex64`).

A (cut down example) function takes some configuration struct `config`, and depending on that input generates a potential value at an index `idx`:

```
fn potential(config: &Config, idx: &Index3) -> Result<f64, Error> {
    let num = &config.grid.size;
    match config.potential {
        PotentialType::NoPotential => Ok(0.0),
        PotentialType::Cube => {
            if (idx.x > num.x / 4 && idx.x <= 3 * num.x / 4) &&
               (idx.y > num.y / 4 && idx.y <= 3 * num.y / 4) &&
               (idx.z > num.z / 4 && idx.z <= 3 * num.z / 4) {
                Ok(-10.0)
            } else {
                Ok(0.0)
            }
        }
        PotentialType::Coulomb => {
            let r = config.grid.dn * (calculate_r2(idx, &config.grid)).sqrt();
            if r < config.grid.dn {
                Ok(-1. / config.grid.dn)
            } else {
                Ok(-1. / r)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I now wish to add a `ComplexCoulomb` match which returns a `Complex64` value:

```
PotentialType::ComplexCoulomb => {
    let r = config.grid.dn * (calculate_r2(idx, &config.grid)).sqrt();
    if r < config.grid.dn {
        Ok(Complex64::new(-1. / config.grid.dn, 1.))
    } else {
        Ok(Complex64::new(-1. / r, 1.))
    }
}
```

This function is an early entry point in my program, which fills an `ndarray::Array3`; currently I'm operating on a number of variables with the type `ndarray::Array3<f64>` - so I need to generalise the whole program, not just this function.

**How can I extend this program to use both types based on the input from `config`?** This struct comes from parsing a configuration file on disk and will match a number of `PotentialType::Complex*` values.

I'm aware of two possible options, but am unsure if either fits my criteria.

1. Use something similar to [Either](https://docs.rs/either/1.1.0/either/) and return `Left` for real and `Right` for complex; then use additional logic to treat the values separately in other functions.
2. Use generic types. This isn't something I've done too much of before and [generalisation over many types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810793/how-can-i-create-an-is-prime-function-that-is-generic-over-various-integer-types) seems like a fair chunk of complicated alteration of my current code base. Is there a way to reduce the complexity here?

If you have any other suggestions I'd love to hear them!

Comment: This question is tricky for its "suggestions" nature (it hits the "too broad" borderline in my opinion). In particular, you have listed two options without showing an attempt of turning them into code. Even if we wanted, we could not show "how to reduce the complexity". Showing some more code could improve the question's quality. Regardless, we can already lay some facts on the table: Even if the function returns a `Result<T, Error>` (where `T` could be `f64`, `Complex64`, ...), we can't have a runtime field in `config` choosing `T`. In the worst case, you might need 2 function instances.

Comment: _we can't have a runtime field in `config` choosing `T` ...you might need 2 function instances_ <- This may indeed be my answer actually. Will look into that and edit my question soon if the other options still fit. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be a lot of code change, but using generic parameters is probably the most flexible approach, and it won't impact performance. Passing around an `enum` will be less performant, partly because the enum will be bigger (the size of the larger variant plus a tag to discriminate between them) and partly because the enum variant will have to be frequently checked.

One thing that can get cumbersome is the potentially long list of traits that constrain your type parameter. This can be done on the `impl` level, rather than on each function, to save repetition. There isn't currently a way to alias a set of traits, which would make this more ergonomic, but there is an [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1733) approved for that.

I made a very [similar change in the Euclid library](https://github.com/servo/euclid/commit/b8166e24b0f294eb103e8717d4de755aa5989b91). It was more than a year ago, so much has changed since then, both in Rust and in that library, but a quick look over that commit should still give you an idea of the amount of changes necessary.

This is the [current state](https://github.com/servo/euclid/blob/f33d6e2808a31b42bb013adafc967bacba140eca/src/transform3d.rs#L113-L122) of the same (renamed) implementation:

```
impl <T, Src, Dst> TypedTransform3D<T, Src, Dst>
where T: Copy + Clone +
         Add<T, Output=T> +
         Sub<T, Output=T> +
         Mul<T, Output=T> +
         Div<T, Output=T> +
         Neg<Output=T> +
         ApproxEq<T> +
         PartialOrd +
         Trig +
         One + Zero {

  // methods of TypedTransform3D defined here...

}
```

Some of those traits (`Trig`, `One`, `Zero`) are actually [defined inside the crate](https://github.com/servo/euclid/blob/0f3afcc9c183b5a21a087c9120563d22c03ed27d/src/num.rs), as they aren't in the standard library.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I'll take a look into your code and try to get a MWE of mine in a similar fashion. Will mark your answer as correct once I've verified something.