# Function parameter of different integer types in Rust

Tags: rust, constraints, overloading, traits

How would I do the following if Rust supported two `percent` functions?

```rust
fn percent(x: u8) -> f32 {
    x as f32 / 100.0
}
fn percent(x: u16) -> f32 {
    x as f32 / 100.0
}
```

If I try a generic data type like the following:

```rust
fn percent<T>(x: T) -> f32 {
    x as f32 / 100.0
}
```

I get the error

> non-primitive cast: `T` as `f32`

Can I constrain `T` with some kind of integer trait?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any trait that specifies numeric functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296351/is-there-any-trait-that-specifies-numeric-functionality)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810793/how-can-i-create-an-is-prime-function-that-is-generic-over-various-integer-types for a "more advanced" version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to only support `u8` and `u16` type, then:

```
fn percent<T: Into<f32>>(x: T) -> f32 {
    x.into() / 100.0
}
```

is enough, since both `u8` and `u16` can be losslessly converted into a `f32`. If you want to generically convert, say a `u64` to `f64`, where a loss of precision can occur, you could use [`ApproxInto`](https://docs.rs/conv/0.3.3/conv/trait.ApproxInto.html) trait from `conv`.

```
fn percent<T: ApproxInto<f64>>(x: T) -> Result<f64, T::Err> {
    x.approx_into().map(|v| v / 100.0)
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you. Is there a slight performance penalty with the `Into<f32>` approach?

Comment: @at. There should not be any since compiler will generate separate copies of code each time you call the function with different types. However sometimes there may be a bug in the compiler. See this article if you want to know more: https://www.joshmcguigan.com/blog/cost-of-indirection-rust/