# Is it possible to write a generic integer length function in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust

I wrote a length function for `u32`. I could easily copy/paste/edit to other int types, but when I try to use generics I'm getting stuck. Are there concepts I'm  misunderstanding?

The passing length function

```
fn len_int(n: u32) -> u32 { // 0
    std::iter::repeat_with({
        let mut l = 0;
        // can't call pow on ambiguous numeric type
        move || match n / 10u32.pow(l) { // 1
            0 => 0,
            _ => {
                l += 1;
                1
            }
        }
    })
        .take_while(|&x| x != 0)
        // count returns usize
        .count() as u32 // 2
}
```

A failing generic length function: I

```
fn len_int<T>(n: T) -> T
where
    T: Copy + Clone,
{
    std::iter::repeat_with({
        let mut l = 0;
        move || match n / 10.pow(l) {
            //1
            0 => 0,
            _ => {
                l += 1;
                1
            }
        }
    })
    .take_while(|&x| x != 0)
    .count() at T // 2
}
```

The compiler tells me I can't
`call method pow on ambiguous numeric type {integer}`
`cannot divide T by type error`
Or convert `count()` at the end with an `as T`, since T is not a primitive type.
[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2152a8cdff09b95f807fa49a23b07917)

Comment: How/where is it failing? Include the error messages and details.

Comment: The provided playground link leads to completely different code…

Comment: @jmb, Sorry that seems to happen sometimes, forget to check it. it works now.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810793/how-can-i-create-an-is-prime-function-that-is-generic-over-various-integer-types for dealing with generic integer types.
Also, some exponent math tells me that no matter what integer you pass in, you'll never overflow `usize` which is what `.count()` returns. Therefore, you really should just return `usize`.

Comment: Also, the simplest method of calculating the number of digits a number occupies in a given base (10 in this case), is to that the log of that number in said base. In this case, log base ten of x. Then, taking the ceiling of that makes it a whole number. Example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=761d3598c016dea5c31ae272f69ef33d

Comment: @OptimisticPeach except that this may give wrong results for large numbers that loose precision when converted to a `f64`. The simplest exact method is to repeatedly divide by 10 ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c0cd4f07339b3d419ad8b912aefd6349)).

Comment: @Jmb, yes, but unless we're dealing with numbers greater than 2^53, we should be fine. Then again, it's all up to OP.

Comment: See this possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69297477/getting-the-length-of-an-int/76442105#76442105)

Answer (score 0):

You may have specific types in your mind, but the compiler doesn't know that. To the compiler a generic type `T` can be *totally anything*. It can be a string. It can be a reference to a function pointer. It can be a vector of file handles. *Anything*. So it will require your code to work with all of these possible types at the same time.

To work with more specific types, you must declare ahead of time *everything* you want the type to support. The compiler won't let you use any operation you haven't declared.

There's no trait for `.pow` in the Rust's standard library, so you can't declare that out of the box. You can make one yourself, or use [num-traits](https://lib.rs/crates/num-traits).

Answer (score 0):

We can define a trait and then implement the trait for the concrete types you want to support in your generic function:

```
pub trait IntLenExt<T> {
    fn is_divis(&self, power: u32) -> bool;
    fn cast_count(count: usize) -> T;
}

impl IntLenExt<u32> for u32 {
    fn is_divis(&self, power: u32) -> bool {
        self / 10u32.pow(power) == 0
    }

    fn cast_count(count: usize) -> u32 {
        count as u32
    }
}

impl IntLenExt<u64> for u64 {
    fn is_divis(&self, power: u32) -> bool {
        self / 10u64.pow(power) == 0
    }

    fn cast_count(count: usize) -> u64 {
        count as u64
    }
}

fn len_int<T>(n: T) -> T
where
    T: Copy + Clone + IntLenExt<T>,
{
    T::cast_count(std::iter::repeat_with({
        let mut l = 0;
        move || match n.is_divis(l) {
            //1
            true => 0,
            false => {
                l += 1;
                1
            }
        }
    })
    .take_while(|&x| x != 0)
    .count()) // 2
}


fn main() {
    let input: u64 = 100;
    println!("len_int({}) => {}", input, len_int(input));
}
```