# Getting the length of an int

Tags: rust

I am trying to get the length (the number of digits when interpreted in decimal) of an `int` in rust. I found a way to do it, however am looking for method that comes from the primitive itself. This is what I have:

```rust
let num = 90.to_string();
println!("num: {}", num.chars().count())
// num: 2
```

I am looking at https://docs.rs/digits/0.3.3/digits/struct.Digits.html#method.length. is this a good candidate? How do I use it? Or are there other crates that does it for me?

One liners with less type conversion is the ideal solution I am looking for.

Comment: Is ```90.to_string().len()``` what you need?

Comment: i like that one @hzqelf - the ideal case would be a func that does not change the type to string

Comment: You can use the log of the number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could loop and check how often you can divide the number by 10 before it becomes a single digit.
Or in the other direction (because division is slower than multiplication), check how often you can multiply `10*10*...*10` until you reach the number:

```rust
fn length(n: u32, base: u32) -> u32 {
    let mut power = base;
    let mut count = 1;
    while n >= power {
        count += 1;
        if let Some(new_power) = power.checked_mul(base) {
            power = new_power;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    count
}
```

Since rust 1.67, you can use:

```rust
n.checked_ilog10().unwrap_or(0) + 1
```

Comment: i was more looking for a one liner sort of. I can't shake off the thought that such a one liner should exist :/ . great answer nonetheless

Comment: @AthulMuralidhar I'm curious as to what you find useful with one liner in such a context.

Comment: No need to worry about division being slower than multiplication if you’re dividing by a constant. The optimiser will represent the division as multiplication by inverse anyway.

Comment: @user What integer constant can you multiply a `u32` by to divide it by 10?

Comment: @trentcl [3435973837](https://godbolt.org/z/57d5d7W1a).

Comment: @user3840170 I am aware of this trick [but a multiplication is still simpler](https://godbolt.org/z/EsP7ooGjP). Your claim that optimization makes division no slower than multiplication does not hold water.

Comment: Compilers sometimes transform more aggressively than you'd think. It turns out that my `length` function, when called with a compile-time constant 10, doesn't multiply anything at all; it [just gets turned into a series of `if` statements](https://godbolt.org/z/E7W365vfM)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a one-liner that doesn't require strings or floating point:

```
println!("num: {}", successors(Some(n), |&n| (n >= 10).then(|| n / 10)).count());
```

It simply counts the number of times the initial number needs to be divided by 10 in order to reach 0.

---

EDIT: the first version of this answer used `iterate` from the (excellent and highly recommended) [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate, but @trentcl pointed out that `successors` from the stdlib does the same. For reference, here is the version using `iterate`:

```
println!("num: {}", iterate(n, |&n| n / 10).take_while(|&n| n > 0).count().max(1));
```

Comment: You could do much the same in `std` with [`successors`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.successors.html). `std`-only version: `successors(Some(n), |&n| (n >= 10).then(|| n / 10)).count()` (this comment does not constitute programming advice)

Comment: @trentcl Nice, thanks! I was actually looking for something like `successors()`, but failed to find it and settled for `itertools::iterate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (barely) one-liner that's faster than doing a string conversion, using std::iter stuff:

```
let some_int = 9834;
let decimal_places = (0..).take_while(|i| 10u64.pow(*i) <= some_int).count();
```

Comment: Neat, but has an overflow error for inputs greater than 1 billion.

Comment: @Daniel thanks, changed the base to u64

Comment: The overflow is still there, it's just moved to inputs greater than or equal to 10 quintillion. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef5c7c0e346ce3315adbc7ed733f946c

Comment: True, but if the input stays i/u32 it's fine.

Comment: Or not, that made some_int to be inferred as u64 (because it needs to be).. damn

Answer (score 1):

The first method below relies on the following formula, where `a` and `b` are the logarithmic bases.

```
log<a>( x ) = log<b>( x ) / log<b>( a )

log<a>( x ) = log<2>( x ) / log<2>( a )  // Substituting 2 for `b`.
```

The following function can be applied to finding the number of digits for bases that are a power of 2. This approach is very fast.

```rust
fn num_digits_base_pow2(n: u64, b: u32) -> u32
{
    (63 - n.leading_zeros()) / (31 - b.leading_zeros()) + 1
}
```

The bits are counted for both `n` (the number we want to represent) and `b` (the base) to find their log2 floor values. Then the adjusted ratio of these values gives the ceiling log value in the desired base.

For a general purpose approach to finding the number of digits for arbitrary bases, the following should suffice.

```rust
fn num_digits(n: u64, b: u32) -> u32
{
    (n as f64).log(b as f64).ceil() as u32
}
```

Comment: Performance-wise, floating-point `log` is a single HW instruction, which will be faster than a SW loop. However, you can replace your `while` loops using [`leading_zeros`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.i32.html#method.leading_zeros): `n_floor_log2 = 32-x.leading_zeros()`

Answer (score 0):

if num is signed:

```
let digits = (num.abs() as f64 + 0.1).log10().ceil() as u32;
```

Answer (score -4):

A nice property of numbers that is always good to have in mind is that the number of digits required to write a number $x$ in base $n$ is actually $\lceil log_n(x + 1) \rceil$.

Therefore, one can simply write the following function (notice the cast from `u32` to `f32`, since integers don't have a log function).

```
fn length(n: u32, base: u32) -> u32 {
    let n = (n+1) as f32;
    n.log(base as f32).ceil() as u32
}
```

You can easily adapt it for negative numbers. For floating point numbers this might be a bit (i.e. a lot) more tricky.

To take into account Daniel's comment about the pathological cases introduced by using f32, note that, with nightly Rust, integers have a logarithm method. (Notice that, imo, those are implementation details, and you should more focus on understanding the algorithm than the implementation.):

```
#![feature(int_log)]

fn length(n: u32, base: u32) -> u32 {
    n.log(base) + 1
}
```

Comment: Not every `u32` fits into a `f32` without rounding error, so your solution ends up returning the wrong result in some cases, e.g. length(0x8000047f, 2) = 31, but length(0x80000480, 2) = 32.
Also, you have an overflow bug, `(n+1)` crashes for `n=0xffffffff`

Comment: @Daniel I technically agree with you (and I updated the answer accordingly). That being said, OP might want to have a look at Hacker's delight for nice mathematical tricks like this one : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker's_Delight

Comment: The problem with these "simple" approaches is that they often just don't work. For example, this returns 5 for both 9999 and 10000.

Comment: @user4815162342 I disagree with you. The error you mentionned is just due to the fact that I wrote the example quickly (and was easily fixed), not to the fact of a deep fallacy in the reasoning. Typically, approaches based on logarithm *will* fail on case where  `n = 0`. Yes, this is known, and it is not important *in the answer*. The purpose of answering questions is to give an approach, then OP can integrate that into a more robust context. I would argue that having a logarithm approach is better than creating a string and counting, or having a loop (except, maybe, in the case of base 2).

Comment: @trentcl Daniel has already mentionned *nicely* the rounding error, which I have corrected, you simply need to read the second part of the post.

Comment: I have read the whole post, thanks, and no, adding a second non-buggy option (which only works for people on nightly who are willing to rely on unstable features) does not erase the problems in the first snippet. If you write code with bugs in it the solution is to fix the bugs, not to write more code.